# Exploding a text file with commas and newlines

Tags: php, explode

If I have a text file:

```
Ramon,19,Libra   
Renata,25,Aries   
Roxy,52,Leo
```

If I am to create an array:

```
print_r(explode(",", $str));
```

How do I account for the newlines?

Comment: file() Reads an entire file into an array.

Comment: it splits on the line breaks

Comment: yes, file() with do the explode for you on the line breaks then you loop though its output to explode on the commas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you want, but try `file()`:

```
$lines = file('/path/to/file.txt');
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $data[] = explode(',', $line);
}
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 5):

Another good way is use [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

```
foreach(file('/path/to/file.txt') as $line) {
    $data[] = str_getcsv($line);
}

var_dump($data);
```

And returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ramon
            [1] => 19
            [2] => Libra
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Renata
            [1] => 25
            [2] => Aries
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Roxy
            [1] => 52
            [2] => Leo
        )

)
```

Or you can use the [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) function

Comment: This looks like a standard csv, str_getcsv method can handle several formats.

Comment: I like this better, my file had quoted text, like "Roxy","52","Leo" and the parsed values included the quotation marks, so $data = '"Roxy"'. Using fgetcsv() removed the string delimiters.

Answer (score 3):

just another way it could be done

```
$filestring = file_get_contents('...path to file...');
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL,$filestring);
foreach($lines as $line) {
     $data[] = explode(',', $line);
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: You should use $data = array_merge($data, explode(',', $line)) to get a single array.